# NPM Runner works in VS 2017 but not in Vs 2019

Tags: visual-studio, npm, webpack

I have a project that is using npm and webpack for our CSS and JavaScript bundling, which works just fine in VS 2017.

However, we are now using VS 2019 and after installing the extensions for both the NPM and Webpack Task Runners to be the same as the VS 2017 installation.

In VS 2019, I get the following error.

```
One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D".
```

So, I opened VS 2017 with same project and it still operates fine, bundling CSS and JavaScript with no errors.

This was a known issue in the preview VS 2019 releases, my current versions in

Software versions:
 - VS 2019 Version 16.2.3
 - VS 2017 Version 15.9.15
 - NPM Task Runner 1.4.90 (same for both)
 - Webpack Task Runner 1.5.94 (same for both)

Does anyone know how to fix this, as currently I am having to open VS 2017 just to run the Task Runner?

**UPDATE**

Interesting side note. If I open up a command prompt and run

```
npm run build
```

from the project folder, it works, so is this just some fault within the task runner?

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Webpack requires you to install Webpack CLI on your own now.

I think somehow, VS 2017 has locked into a specific version of Webpack while VS 2019 has installed latest Webpack due to ^ version flag in your package.json.

To fix the issue, open up a terminal to the location of package.json and run:

`npm install webpack-cli --save-dev`

Then try again in VS 2019.

Hope this helps!